# DB Error: no such field : Assignee Contact Email

Tags: database

We had to restore a database from server crash to a newer version CiviCRM (4.6.3). We have gotten most of the data moved over but this one has us stumped. We have been getting the error "DB Error: no such field" when we have the "Assignee Contact Email" checked in the Activity Report-Template.

I have gone through and compared the tables: **civicrm_activity** and **civicrm_activity_contact** to a fresh install of CiviCRM 4.6.3. All Columns, Indexes and Foreign Keys seem to be identical.

Is there some other place I should be checking?

Thanks again for everyone's help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version did your database come from? I could imagine your report still tries to retrieve the assignee contact id from the table civicrm_activity_assignment (prior to CiviCRM version 4.4) rather than from civicrm_activity_contact?

Comment: Thank you, we are coming 4.1 so I believe this to be the problem. What's the best way to correct this issue?

Comment: Is the report a customized one? If so, you will need to adapt it to retrieve the assignee from the table civicrm_activity_contact with a specific record_type. If it was based on the core activity summary report, I would start by creating a new report from that template?

Comment: It's a custom template, in order to retrieve the assignee from the table civicrm_activity_contact, do I need to edit the core or can this be done through the database?

Comment: You should not edit the core in any circumstance :-) If it is a custom template you will have to edit it or get it edited? It should not be a big job, are you able to do that yourself?

Comment: I think I can poke around enough to figure it out. It's all about trial and error. Thanks again for your help. I will dig deeper into it.

Comment: The problem will probably be in the query in the $sql variable. It will probably try to access the file civicrm_activity_assignee, and possibly the civicrm_activity_target. Both are now in civicrm_activity_contact with record_type 1 = assignee and record_type 3 = target

Answer (score 1):

Since your codebase has been upgraded, and your question doesn't mention running the upgrader as part of this, make sure you've followed the upgrade instructions (as best as they can apply after a server crash).

- For Drupal, visit `?q=civicrm/upgrade&reset=1` or `civicrm/upgrade?reset=1`
- For WordPress, visit `wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/upgrade&reset=1`
- For Joomla, visit `/administrator/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/upgrade&reset=1`

For upgrade documentation, refer to [the upgrade documentation page for your CMS](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Installation+and+Upgrades). If your replacement server differs from your previous one, also review documentation for [moving an existing installation to a new server or location](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Moving+an+Existing+Installation+to+a+New+Server+or+Location).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, I get this error when I try to upgrade and reset: Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
Your database has already been upgraded to CiviCRM 4.6.3

Comment: If you can [turn on debugging](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Debugging+for+developers#Debuggingfordevelopers-EnableDebugging) that will help you see the error. Otherwise there is a CiviCRM log file (see "log files" in linked page) in your installation which records the error message. You'll need to make sense of this error message to identify the unexpected/incorrectly named DB column.